# Ubuntu: All the files on my computer seem to accessed within the range of 30 minutes a month ago

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

Out of curiosity, I stated checking the last accessed date of my files on my home folder. Surprisingly I found out almost every file has access time around `2018-03-01 17:59:42.689118604` even files I haven't touched for more than a year. How do I find out how and which program made that access?

Comment: Did you backup/copy your home folder around that time?

Comment: @DavidPostill checked that but I didn't. I installed clamav around that time I guess. But my bash history shows I only did `clamscan /` without `-r` option. Could I have done full scan but is not in my bash history?

Comment: That would depend on exactly how you have your history configured

Comment: @DavidPostill it shows everything. Nothing special.

Comment: `bash` is not the only way to run unix programs ... have you looked for a `clamav` log file?

Comment: @DavidPostill It doesn't create one unless you tell it to. And I don't have the GUI tool for clamav.